# How to connect AWS DynamoDb directly with dart

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a messaging app in flutter and all the messages are stored in AWS DynamoDB. I didn't find any docs on direct support of DynamoDB and Dart. So I first connected DB to NodeJS and used http req from flutter app to get the messages. But its not much reliable. Only if I could find a way to connect it directly I could make the app more speeder. If anyone out there know a way for this please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not an AWS SDK for this programming language. The only thing I can think of is to write code in your programming language that can invoke DynamoDB using Rest. There is an AWS documentation including an example:

[DynamoDB Low-Level API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html)

Comment: And a Dart implementation of that low level API here: https://pub.dev/packages/aws_dynamodb_api

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe try non AWS provided SDKs like this [one](https://github.com/agilord/aws_client). It includes a DynamoDB client. I haven’t used it before, so I can’t vouch for it.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard mentioned, https://pub.dev/packages/aws_dynamodb_api is a good solution.

I integrated DynamoDB in dart as other languages:

```
static var client = DynamoDB(region: 'eu-west-1', 
endpointUrl: "http://localhost:8000", 
credentials: AwsClientCredentials(accessKey: "dummy", secretKey: "dummy"));

static Future<bool> init() async {

var attributeDefinitions = <AttributeDefinition>[
AttributeDefinition(attributeName: "user_id", attributeType: ScalarAttributeType.n)
];

var keySchema = <KeySchemaElement>[
KeySchemaElement(attributeName: "user_id", keyType: KeyType.hash)
];

var throughput = ProvisionedThroughput(readCapacityUnits: 10, writeCapacityUnits: 10);
try 
{
  var response = await client.createTable(attributeDefinitions: attributeDefinitions, keySchema: keySchema, provisionedThroughput: throughput, tableName: "Users");
  print("Created table ${response.tableDescription!.tableName}");
  return true;
} catch(e)
{
  print("Error: $e");
  return false;
}
```

I tested it downloading the docker image of DynamoDB: https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/

Comment: It tells me that the table was created, but no table is seen in the console